# How do I set off a set of async tasks in C# and handle errors with source

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

If I have a set of methods to call, and want to do so asynchronously. I can do this:

```
var status = new DiagnosticsResult();

try
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>
    {
        _someService.Method1(),
        _someService.Method2(),
        _someService.Method3(),
        _someService.Method4(),
        _someService.Method5(),
        _someService.Method6(),
        _someService.Method7(),
        _someService.Method8()
    };

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    foreach (var innerException in ex.InnerExceptions)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

And that is fine if I just want to know that  an error *has* occurred, but what if I need to know which methods throw an exception and which ones succeeded?

Comment: Could you use the stack trace for each exception? That should show you for each error which method caused the exception.

Comment: If I use your code I'm able to use `innerException.TargetSite.Name` and some string manipulation to get the method name if that's what you're looking for. For me a method name Method1 has a TargetSite.Name of `<Method1>b__2_0`

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your list of tasks in scope you can iterate over them in your `catch` or simply after your `Wait` to look for exceptions on `Task.Exception`.

You can use `AggregateException.Handle` with a `Func<Exception, bool>` that will let you filter on the message, the type etc. Additionally if you iterate over the `Aggregate` you should call `Flatten` to line up all your exceptions.

[Exception handling MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit**

> The problem I am facing is that as soon as one throws the rest change to Cancelled state. I need them all to run and pass or fail, then I need to determine the result. I moved the task list outside the try and yes it is updated, but I get 3 "RanToCompletion", 1 "Faulted" and the rest "Cancelled" when #4 fails

It seems as though the approach would be to await each and handle their exceptions individually instead of as group. Two approaches shown below:

```
public async Task Test1() {
    var taskList = new List<Task>() {
         _someService.Method1.ContinueWith(tsk => {
             //handle ex
         }).Unwrap()
    }
    /*
     * or..
     * */
    try {
        await _someService.Method1
    }catch (AggregateException ex) {
        /***
         * Handle ex
         * *//
    }               
}
```

Comment: The problem I am facing is that as soon as one throws the rest change to Cancelled state. I need them all to run and pass or fail, then I need to determine the result. I moved the task list outside the try and yes it is updated, but I get 3 "RanToCompletion", 1 "Faulted" and the rest "Cancelled" when #4 fails.

Comment: Just a thought have you checked the behavior of `WhenAll` likely the same but worth checking. Otherwise, `awaiting` each will give the same which just leaves catching the exception in a `ContinueWith` and `awaiting` their `Unwrap`... not elegant but works.

Comment: Running one await at a time was what I had - and worked. - I was looking for something more elegant but I'm starting to think  I might have been correct in the first place :/

Comment: Maybe the cleanest solution could be an extensions method on an `IEnumerable<Task>` that `await`s all of them in turn and swallows any exception for you to handle later. Still not that ideal. You could name it `Task.WhenAllSuccessful`.  [DREAMING OF MULTIPLE TASKS AGAIN…](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/11/01/dreaming-of-multiple-tasks-again-with-occasional-exceptions/)

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is passing in a token with each Task and enable correlation when evaluating the result:

```
public static Task<WhenAllWithTokenResult<TToken>> WhenAllWithToken<TToken>(Tuple<Task, TToken>[] tasks)
{
    var successfulTasks = new List<Tuple<Task, TToken>>();
    var failedTasks = new List<Tuple<Task, TToken>>();
    var cancelledTasks = new List<Tuple<Task, TToken>>();
    int amountCompleted = 0;
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<WhenAllWithTokenResult<TToken>>();
    // Register ContinueWith callback for each task and add it to the according result list when completed
    foreach (var tuple in tasks)
    {
        var copyOfTuple = tuple;
        tuple.Item1.ContinueWith(_ =>
        {               
            if (_.IsFaulted)
            {
                failedTasks.Add(copyOfTuple);
            }
            else if (_.IsCanceled)
            {
                cancelledTasks.Add(copyOfTuple);
            }
            else if (_.IsCompleted)
            {
                successfulTasks.Add(copyOfTuple);
            }
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref amountCompleted) == tasks.Length)
            {
                // All tasks finished so let's set the result of this method
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(new WhenAllWithTokenResult<TToken>(successfulTasks, failedTasks, cancelledTasks));
            }
        });
    }
    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}

public class WhenAllWithTokenResult<TToken>
{
    public IList<Tuple<Task, TToken>> SuccessfulTasks { get; private set; }
    public IList<Tuple<Task, TToken>> FailedTasks { get; private set; }
    public IList<Tuple<Task, TToken>> CancelledTasks { get; private set; }

    public WhenAllWithTokenResult(IList<Tuple<Task, TToken>> successfulTasks, IList<Tuple<Task, TToken>> failedTasks, IList<Tuple<Task, TToken>> cancelledTasks)
    {
        CancelledTasks = cancelledTasks;
        SuccessfulTasks = successfulTasks;
        FailedTasks = failedTasks;
    }
}
```

and using it like:

```
WhenAllWithTokenResult<string> result = 
    await WhenAllWithToken(
                    new[]
                    {
                        Tuple.Create(_someService.Method1(), "Method1"),
                        Tuple.Create(_someService.Method2(), "Method2"),
                        Tuple.Create(_someService.Method3(), "Method3"),
                        Tuple.Create(_someService.Method4(), "Method4")
                    });

foreach (var item in result.SuccessfulTasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Successful: {0}", item.Item2);
}
foreach (var item in result.FailedTasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed: {0}", item.Item2);
}
foreach (var item in result.CancelledTasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled: {0}", item.Item2);
}
```

Please note 1) The token is a generic and just passed along to allow correlation. So, it can be anything you want. 2) WhenAllWithToken has a different semantic than WhenAll: It returns a task which completes when all input tasks were either successful, failed or cancelled but not before.